# Firebase deploy error - Configuring expiration modes is not permitted

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, schedule

I'm trying to deploy my firebase project but I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Error: 400, Configuring expiration modes is not permitted
```

I haven't found anything on web and I don't know what could it be.

Anyone has encountered the same error?

Thanx

Comment: Can you share your code and describe how you are trying to deploy your project?

Comment: Which code? My project is huge, tons of files :D
I use this script  `REACT_APP_ENV=PROD GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build && firebase use [proj-name] && firebase deploy --only hosting:prod,firestore,functions`

Comment: i solved launching them separately, first `npm run build = REACT_APP_ENV=PROD GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build` then `firebase use [proj-name]` and then `firebase deploy --only functions` and `firebase deploy --only hosting:prod`

Comment: can you also post your solution as the answer? This will make it more visible and other community members would be able to use it

Answer (score 1):

Posting the @ProfLayton's solution as a Community wiki for better visibility.

The error has been fixed by launching the deployment scripts separately:

1. `npm run build = REACT_APP_ENV=PROD GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build`
2. `firebase use [proj-name]`
3. `firebase deploy --only functions`
4. `firebase deploy --only hosting:prod`